# Session variables lost after header redirect

Tags: php, session, session-variables

Session variables lost after header redirect Even i Used `session_start(); in All Pages`

**Here My Code..**

```
<?php 
session_start();
$id=$_REQUEST['id'];
$pid=$_POST['pid'];
$_SESSION['pid']=$_POST['pid'];
```

**Add To Cart Function**

```
include("cart/functions.php");
if($_REQUEST['command']=='add' && $_REQUEST['id']>0){
$id=$_REQUEST['id'];
addtocart($id,1);
header('location:shoppingcart.php');
exit();
}
```

**After Click On This Button $_SESSION['pid']=$_POST['pid'];` Disappear From All Pages?**

```
<input type="button" class="button1" value="Add To Cart" 
 onclick="addtocart(<?php echo $row3['id']?>);" />
</div>
</div></form>
```

Comment: Because you don't POST each page `$_SESSION['pid']=$_POST['pid'];` will probably sometimes not trigger correctly, thus killing your data stored in your session, and thus not validate in your other code-segments. Enable `error_reporting()` and you'll probably see what's going wrong :)

Answer (score 1):

`header('location:shoppingcart.php');` is a forced redirect, there is no POST when this happens, so the line `$_SESSION['pid']=$_POST['pid'];` is going to have no effect. If you must do cookieless sessions, look into `use-trans-sid`: http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.use-trans-sid

Comment: thanks i have done it but can you give me solution for that problem 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15357372/in-php-for-loop-showing-only-one-row-from-mysql-database?noredirect=1#comment21697702_15357372  same problem i'm facing it right now

Answer (score 0):

You probably set `$_SESSION['pid'] = $_POST['pid']` in every request - even if your POST doesn't even have `pid` in it.

Try to change this

```
$_SESSION['pid']=$_POST['pid'];
```

to this

```
if (isset($_POST['pid'])) {
  $_SESSION['pid'] = $_POST['pid'];
}
```