# in php for loop showing only one row from mysql database?

Tags: php, mysql, database, select

in php forloop showing only one row from mysql database?In The `forloop` retrieve only one `row` from mysql database and `for loop repeat that size row again and again` when ever `new product is entered?`

**Page Function**

```
    <?php
if(is_array($_SESSION['cart'])){
echo '<tr bgcolor="#FFFFFF" style="font-weight:bold"><td align="center"><font style="font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;  font-size:14px; color:#000;">Item Code</font></td><td align="center"><font style="font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;  font-size:14px; color:#000;">Product Name</font></td>
<td align="center"><font style="font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;  font-size:14px; color:#000;">Product Image</font></td>
<td><font style="font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;  font-size:14px; color:#000;">Price</font></td>
<td><div><font style="font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;  font-size:14px; color:#000;">Size</font></div></td>
<td><font style="font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;  font-size:14px; color:#000;">Options</font></td></tr>';

 $max=count($_SESSION['cart'] );
 for($i=0;$i<=$max;$i++){
 $id=$_SESSION['cart'][$i]['id'];
 $q=$_SESSION['cart'][$i]['qty'];
 $product=get_product_name($id);
 $image=get_product_image($id);
 $ids=get_id($id);
 $itemcode=get_itemcode($id);
 $size=get_size($id);
 if($q==0) continue;

 ?>
 </table>


 <diiv style="float:left; margin-left:42px;"><font style="font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;  font-size:15px; color:#000;">
 <?php echo $itemcode; ?>
 <input type="hidden" name="itemcode[]" value="<?php echo $itemcode?>" /></font></div><br />

 <div style="float: left;margin-left: 122px; margin-top: -14px;"><font style="font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;  font-size:15px; color:#000;">
 <?php echo $product?>
 <input type="hidden" name="product[]" value="<?php echo $product?>" /></font></div><br />


<div style="float: left;margin-left: 387px;margin-top: -24px;"><font style="font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;  font-size:15px; color:#000;">
<img name="image" id="image" src="admin/uploads/small0_<?php echo $image?>" width="150" height="150">
<input type="hidden" name="image[]" id="image"  value="<?php echo $image?>"  /> </font></div><br />

<div style="float: left;margin-left: 548px;margin-top: -147px;"><font style="font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;  font-size:15px; color:#000;">
<?php echo get_price($id) ?>
<input type="hidden" name="price[]" id="price" value="<?php echo get_price($id)?>" /></font></div><br />

<?php //foreach ($size as $sizes) { ?>
<div style="float: left;margin-left: 625px;margin-top: -149px;"><font style="font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;font-size:15px; color:#000;">
<?php echo $size; ?> 
</font><input type="hidden" name="size" value="<?php echo $size; ?>" /></font></div><?php //}?><br />

<div style="float: left;margin-left:686px;margin-top: -150px;"><a href="javascript:del(<?php echo $id?>)">
<input type="button" class="button5" value="Remove" /></a></div><br /> 
<hr style="width:800px" />  

<?php                   
}
?>

 <?php
 }
 else{
 echo "There are no items in your shopping cart!";
 }
 ?>
```

**Size Query**

```
function get_size($id){
$result=mysql_query("SELECT size FROM mywishlist order by id") or die("My Wish Size Problem"."<br/><br/>".mysql_error());
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
return $row['size'];
}}

 function get_size($id){
 $result=mysql_query("SELECT size FROM mywishlist Where pid='$id'") or die("My Wish   Size Problem"."<br/><br/>".mysql_error());
 while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
 return $row['size'];
}}
```

**Mywishlist Table Screenshot**
[image: now see there are two sizes in the size column]

**Page Screenshot**
[image: page screenshot]

**When I Used This Function**

```
function get_size($id){

$result=mysql_query("SELECT size FROM mywishlist order by id") or die("My Wish Size Problem"."<br/><br/>".mysql_error());

while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
 $size[] = $row['size'];
}

return $size;

}

 <?php foreach ($size as $sizes) { ?>
<div style="float: left;margin-left: 625px;margin-top: -131px;">
<font style="font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;font-size:15px; color:#000;">
<?php echo $sizes; ?> 
<font><input type="hidden" name="size" value="<?php echo $size; ?>" />
</font></div><?php }?><br />
```

**Result After Using Array  & Foreach Loop**

[image]

Comment: am i blind or you dont use $id in getSize function? and you dont have WHERE in SELECT statement.

Comment: [Please, don't use mysql_* functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php) in new code. They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [red box](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Learn about [_prepared statements_](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide which.

Answer (score 0):

change your function to:

```
function get_size($id){

$result=mysql_query("SELECT size FROM mywishlist order by id") or die("My Wish Size Problem"."<br/><br/>".mysql_error());

while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
 $size[] = $row['size'];
}

return $size;

}
```

Because in your function you only returned first row and return terminates the while loop.

Comment: if he have $id parameter in method, i think he wanted to fetch only size from certain id. But he is missing WHERE.

Comment: akam please i uploaded new image after using array and foreach loop

Comment: are you sure $id is changed in loop? did you try to print it?

Comment: and you surely needs WHERE in your query and you need to use $id parameter.

Comment: even i used it $result=mysql_query("SELECT size FROM mywishlist Where pid='$id'") but same result

Comment: you cant use pid, both results have pid the same (32). you must use unique identifier.

Comment: should i use mywishlist.id ?

Comment: yes,use id. make sure $id variable is changing (meaning $_SESSION['cart'][0]['id'] contain id for the first item and $_SESSION['cart'][1]['id'] for the second).